# How to fix sql error cannot add or update a child row, a foreign key constraint fails?

Tags: sql, mysql

```
CREATE DATABASE BOOKMANAGEMENTSYSTEM;

USE BOOKMANAGEMENTSYSTEM;

CREATE TABLE Employee (
    emp_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    emp_name VARCHAR(20),
    emp_role VARCHAR(30)
);

CREATE TABLE Customer (
    cust_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    cust_name VARCHAR(20),
    cust_add VARCHAR(30)
);

CREATE TABLE Supplier (
    supp_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    supp_name VARCHAR(20),
    supp_contact VARCHAR(40)
);


CREATE TABLE Book ( 
  book_id INT, 
  book_price DECIMAL(10, 2), 
  genre VARCHAR(25), 
  book_name VARCHAR(20), 
  invoice_id INT, 
  PRIMARY KEY (book_id) 
  );


CREATE TABLE Inventory ( 
  inventory_id INT, 
  category VARCHAR(20), 
  selling_price DECIMAL(10, 2), 
  invoice_id INT, 
  PRIMARY KEY (inventory_id)
);

CREATE TABLE Invoice ( 
  invoice_id INT, 
  supp_id INT, 
  book_id INT, 
  inventory_id INT, 
  PRIMARY KEY (invoice_id)
);

CREATE TABLE Payment ( 
  pay_id INT, 
  item_qty INT, 
  Tprice DECIMAL (10,2), 
  order_id INT,
  PRIMARY KEY (pay_id)
);

CREATE TABLE Orders ( 
  order_id INT, 
  order_qty INT, 
  date DATE, 
  inventory_id INT,
  book_id INT,
  cust_id INT,
  emp_id INT,
  PRIMARY KEY (order_id)
);

ALTER TABLE Book    
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Book_Invoice FOREIGN KEY (invoice_id)     
REFERENCES Invoice (invoice_id);

ALTER TABLE Inventory    
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Inventory_Invoice FOREIGN KEY (invoice_id)     
REFERENCES Invoice (invoice_id);

ALTER TABLE Invoice
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Invoice_Book FOREIGN KEY (book_id) REFERENCES Book (book_id),
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Invoice_Supplier FOREIGN KEY (supp_id) REFERENCES Supplier (supp_id),
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Invoice_Inventory FOREIGN KEY (inventory_id) REFERENCES Inventory (inventory_id);

ALTER TABLE Payment   
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Payment_Orders FOREIGN KEY (order_id)     
REFERENCES Orders (order_id);

ALTER TABLE Orders
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Orders_Inventory FOREIGN KEY (inventory_id) REFERENCES Inventory (inventory_id),
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Orders_Book FOREIGN KEY (book_id) REFERENCES Book (book_id),
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Orders_Customer FOREIGN KEY (cust_id) REFERENCES Customer (cust_id),
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Orders_Employee FOREIGN KEY (emp_id) REFERENCES Employee (emp_id);

INSERT INTO Employee (emp_id, emp_name, emp_role) 
VALUES ('101', 'Amirul', 'Cashier'), 
   ('102', 'Nurin', 'Store Manager'),
   ('103', 'Diana', 'Admin'),
   ('104', 'Faris', 'Inventory Manager'),
   ('105', 'Christy', 'Sales Coordinator');
                                                    
INSERT INTO Customer (cust_id, cust_name, cust_add) 
VALUES ('201', 'Nuria', 'Taman Mawar, 88400'),
   ('202', 'Stephan', 'Taman Lily, 88400'),
   ('203', 'Khairul', 'Taman Kemboja, 88400'),
   ('204', 'Maria', 'Taman Tulip, 88400'),
   ('205', 'Rina', 'Taman Bunga Raya, 88400');
                                                       
INSERT INTO Supplier (supp_id, supp_name, supp_contact) 
VALUES ('301', 'Scholastic', 'scholastic@book.com'),
   ('302', 'Karya Seni', 'karyaseni@book.com'),
   ('303', 'Simon & Schuster', 'simonschuster@book.com'),
   ('304', 'Bloomsbury', 'bloomsbury@book.com'),
   ('305', 'HarperVia', 'harpervia@book.com');
                                                           
INSERT INTO Book (book_id, book_price, genre, book_name, invoice_id) 
VALUES ('401', '25.50', 'young adult', 'Thea Stilton', '00001'),
   ('402', '20.20', 'drama', 'Twisted fate', '00002'),
       ('403', '32.70', 'comedy', 'Dork diaries', '00003'),
   ('404', '45.60', 'fantasy', 'Harry Potter', '00004'),
   ('405', '27.00', 'non-fiction', 'Almond', '00005');             
                                                                         
INSERT INTO Inventory (inventory_id, category, selling_price, invoice_id) 
VALUES ('501', 'young adult fiction', '28.50', '00001'),
   ('502', 'adult fiction', '25.20', '00002'),
       ('503', 'young adult fiction', '35.70', '00003'),
   ('504', 'adult fiction', '50.60', '00004'),
   ('505', 'adult non-fiction', '30.00', '00005');      
   
INSERT INTO Invoice (invoice_id, supp_id, book_id, inventory_id) 
VALUES ('00001', '301', '401', '501'),
   ('00002', '302', '402', '502'),
   ('00003', '303', '403', '503'),
   ('00004', '304', '404', '504'),
   ('00005', '305', '405', '505');      
   
INSERT INTO Payment (pay_id, item_qty, Tprice, order_id) 
VALUES ('20001', '1', '28.50', '10001'),
   ('20002', '2', '50.40', '10002'),
   ('20003', '1', '35.70', '10003'),
   ('20004', '2', '101.20', '10004'),
   ('20005', '1', '30.00', '10005');   
                                                            
INSERT INTO Orders (order_id, order_qty, date, inventory_id, book_id, cust_id, emp_id) 
VALUES ('10001', '1', '2024-01-11', '501', '401', '201', '101'),
   ('10002', '2', '2024-01-12', '502', '402', '202', '102'),
   ('10003', '1', '2024-01-13', '503', '403', '203', '103'),
   ('10004', '2', '2024-01-14', '504', '404', '204', '104'),
   ('10005', '1', '2024-01-15', '505', '405', '205', '105');`
```

I tried inserting the values to all the tables, but it shows me this error instead :

> #1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`bookmanagementsystem`.`book`, CONSTRAINT `FK_Book_Invoice` FOREIGN KEY (`invoice_id`) REFERENCES `Invoice` (`invoice_id`))

which part do I need to fix? what do I do to enter the values into the table? I tried following the tutorial online but nothing seem to work.

Comment: You have to insert the invoice before you can insert a book that references that invoice.

Comment: You can't have bidirectional foreign keys. You shouldn't have `book.invoice_id` and `invoice.book_id`. This means you have to insert the book before the invoice and also insert the invoice before the book, which obviously isn't possible.